# Check if username exists in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello guys i am building a registration form and i want to store the usernames in an `ArrayList`

Adding the username is fine but when i check for duplicates it still adds the same username

My code so far:

```
private void clickEventLeftPanel() {
        registerBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                unameReg = registerUser.getText();
                regPass = registerPassword.getPassword();
                regRetype = registerRetype.getPassword();
                set = new ArrayList();
                if (unameReg.isEmpty()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HomeAssignmentJavaLab.this, "Username is Required", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (regPass.length == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HomeAssignmentJavaLab.this, "Password is Required", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (regPass.length < 6) {
                    weakness.setText("Very Weak");
                    weakness.setBackground(Color.red);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HomeAssignmentJavaLab.this, "Your password is very weak please enter a more complex password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (regPass.length < 8) {
                    weakness.setText("Moderate");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HomeAssignmentJavaLab.this, "Your password is moderate please enter a more complex password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    weakness.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                } else if (regRetype.length == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HomeAssignmentJavaLab.this, "Please retype your password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (regPass != regRetype && regPass.length != regRetype.length) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HomeAssignmentJavaLab.this, "Passwords do not match", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    weakness.setText("Strong");
                    weakness.setBackground(Color.green);
                    if(set.contains(unameReg)){
                        System.err.println("Already exists");
                    }else{
                        set.add(unameReg);

                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HomeAssignmentJavaLab.this, "Registration Successful user " + registerUser.getText() + " was entered", "Success", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }

                weakness.setText("");
                weakness.setBackground(getBackground());
                registerUser.setText("");
                registerPassword.setText("");
                registerRetype.setText("");
            }


    });
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `java.util.Set`, if you dislike duplicate elements in the list of items.

Comment: Your duplicate check `if(set.contains(unameReg))` doesn't actually block the `"Registration Successful"` message from showing up. It only blocks the `set.add(unameReg);` line, because that is what is in the `else` block.

Comment: the point is that it doesnt gives me the error message already exists....dont mind the optionpane dialog

Comment: @Eleni You're assigning a new (empty) list to `set`, so `set.contains(unameReq)` should always be `false`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `set` every time you add `unameReg`. You have to create it once.